# POST request with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm making a basic mobile app to interact with a nosql database.  So far, I've had no problems using Volley.  I have two main entities in my database, and both are storing all of their attributes as strings.  With one entity, Volley's GET and POST works fine, but with the other entity, the GET request works but not the POST request (some parameters are null).

The page I'm having trouble with is intended to let the user edit data he/she has already put in.  I first populate it with a Volley GET request.  That works fine, and all of the parameters display properly.  Then, if the user alters the data and submits it, it is submitted with a POST request, which fails because some of the parameters are null.

I've narrowed the error down (I think) to the getParams() function.  The generals and victors variables are populated, but all of the others come back as null.  Again, all of my variables are strings, so it doesn't seem like an incompatible data type.

Here's the code I have:

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    if (response != null) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(EditDeleteDetail.this, "Detail Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("generals", generals);
            Log.d("Params generals", generals);
            params.put("victor", victor);
            Log.d("Params victor", victor);
            params.put("ramifications", ramifications);
            Log.d("Params ramifications", ramifications);
            params.put("casualties", casualties);
            Log.d("Params casualties", casualties);
            params.put("startdate", startdate);
            Log.d("Params startdate", startdate);
            params.put("enddate", enddate);

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);

    return true;
}
```

Here's the code for the API, which I did in Python.  I can manually POST using curl tests or the Postman app, and all of the data is correctly populated and saved in the database:

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import db_models
import json

class Detail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self, **kwargs):
    """Creates a Detail entity

    POST Body Variables:
    generals- String. List of commanding generals
    victor - String. Winner (if any) of battle
    ramifications - String. Results and implications of the battle
    casualties - Stored as string, but also includes integers.  Participating armies' casualties
    startdate - Date property
    enddate - Date property
    """
    if 'application/json' not in self.request.accept:
        self.response.status = 406
        self.response.status_message = "Not Acceptable, API only supports application/json MIME type"
        return
    if 'did' in kwargs:
        curr_det = ndb.Key(db_models.Details, int(kwargs['did'])).get()
        generals = self.request.get('generals', default_value=None)
        victor = self.request.get('victor', default_value=None)
        ramifications = self.request.get('ramifications', default_value=None)
        casualties = self.request.get('casualties', default_value=None)
        startdate = self.request.get('startdate', default_value=None)
        enddate = self.request.get('enddate', default_value=None)
        if generals:
            curr_det.generals = generals
        if victor:
            curr_det.victor = victor
        if ramifications: 
            curr_det.ramifications = ramifications
        if casualties:
            curr_det.casualties = casualties
        if startdate:
            curr_det.startdate = startdate
        if enddate:
            curr_det.enddate = enddate
        curr_det.put()
        out = curr_det.to_dict()
        self.response.write(json.dumps(out))

    else: 
        new_detail = db_models.Details()  #making a new Detail
        generals = self.request.get('generals', default_value=None)
        victor = self.request.get('victor', default_value=None)
        ramifications = self.request.get('ramifications', default_value=None)
        casualties = self.request.get('casualties', default_value=None)
        startdate = self.request.get('startdate', default_value=None)
        enddate = self.request.get('enddate', default_value=None)
        if generals:
            new_detail.generals = generals
        else:
            self.response.status = 400
            self.response.status_message = "Invalid request, Commanding generals are Required"
            return
        if victor:      
            new_detail.victor = victor
        if ramifications:
            new_detail.ramifications = ramifications
        if casualties:
            new_detail.casualties = casualties
        if startdate:
            new_detail.startdate = startdate
        if enddate:
            new_detail.enddate = enddate    
        key = new_detail.put()  #this saves the new Detail in the database
        out = new_detail.to_dict()      #then we return the thing we just made
        self.response.write(json.dumps(out))
        return
```

Comment: `but all of the others come back as null`. Come back from where? And where do you see them null?

Comment: where are those params assigned ?

Comment: `Volley's GET and POST works fine`. Ok. They work fine. `, but with the other entity, the GET request works but not the POST request (some parameters are null).`. Suddendy they do not work fine? Which other entity?

Comment: `which fails because some of the parameters are null.`. Where do you see that parameters are null? At server side i think. Please show your server script.

Comment: I'm seeing the values as null when I do all of those Log.d statements in the getParams() method, and also when I debug it and it steps through assigning values to those variables.  I should mention also that I have checked the API that I'm posting to, and I can manually do POSTs through both CURL tests and through the Postman app and it POSTs the data with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different syntax and Request type for your case:

```
 Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new ArrayMap<>();
jsonParams.put("nodeId", null);
jsonParams.put("userId", null);
jsonParams.put("email", "some@gmail.com");
jsonParams.put("userProfile", null);
jsonParams.put("region", null);
jsonParams.put("password", 123);
jsonParams.put("places", new ArrayList());

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
              //print it here and check
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
            {
                if (null != error.networkResponse)
                {
                 //do whatever
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.  It ended up not having anything to do with the Volley code itself; what I had was actually working.  The problem was that I had forgotten that I commented out some of the input verification code, and in doing so, it wasn't picking up the text from those two fields.

Earlier on in the project, I had input verification set up so that users couldn't submit invalid characters.  I didn't have that set up for the date fields, so I commented some of that code out.....including the lines that were calling the getText().toString() method for each field.  So it literally was never pulling in the input from those fields.  It's so obvious in retrospect....... :(

```
            startdate = startDateEditText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(startdate);
            if (!isValidDate(startdate)) {
                startDateEditText.setError("Invalid input.");
                isValidInput = false;
            }

            enddate = endDateEditText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(enddate);
            if (!isValidDate(enddate)) {
                endDateEditText.setError("Invalid input.");
                isValidInput = false;
            }

            if (isValidInput) {
                newPostRequest();
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```