# Unexpected response code 400 android volley error

Tags: android, android-volley, http-status-code-400

[image]When i try to Post a request with android volley it returns the error "Unexpected response code 400", when i run the curl command in git bash it is success.
my curl command is

```
curl -X POST \
  https://sam.vuoto.us/sapi/employee/activity \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjYwZTQxMjczMzMwYTg2ZmRjMjhlMjgzMDVhNDRkYzlhODgzZTI2YTciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vd2F0ZXItc29hbC1zb2NpZXR5IiwiYXVkIjoid2F0ZXItc29hbC1zb2NpZXR5IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTYxNTgyMTEzLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiU1U5aWVnRGhyM2I5cjNnQ1VaelhsOWVRakVKMiIsInN1YiI6IlNVOWllZ0RocjNiOXIzZ0NVWnpYbDllUWpFSjIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NjMzODQxNjIsImV4cCI6MTU2MzM4Nzc2MiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbHZpbkB2dW90b2xhYnMuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOmZhbHNlLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7ImVtYWlsIjpbImFsdmluQHZ1b3RvbGFicy5jb20iXX0sInNpZ25faW5fcHJvdmlkZXIiOiJwYXNzd29yZCJ9fQ.kJi_tVNrc-2Mf4uoVOYuURUpBKs72H3Sr7TyFkO-b5vSzBbv1iBu4PIYkHd7bNZEVxhNfyAg2zNFcwQuQPG9TdSjZ0fPGF1mzdrkOMsKjoBPQIZK2coG24oLoKkkuXtxaWMXe1BlNpLhPcWM9BBoZ0Os2PmXf-PIgGfzrPzQ1nBOt6zAD5rv2H4WEntIA3tRLSHgSrFba0taVjD8Do1drIm7ocfnbDPHKMIeJRj60uzaEj5WjbbaB_MXXpjClVgUR1XF25_QDMA4F1Ok2odTrT1nMofgM_jMVn0s_K2ljU2zCoIKQwe477tx1I4zLfgIyBXI8FWhg03-e08QxvD-Zw' \
  -d '{
    "title":"Test Activity 4",
    "description":"Test Description",
    "activityStreamId": 1401
}'
```

this command works fine.

But when i try this in android it returns error

```
   JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, serverurl,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "other class: "+response);
                        acitvityprog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        JSONObject employee=response.getJSONObject("success");

                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        acitvityprog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
            acitvityprog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
    ){

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("title",titles);
            params.put("description",desc);
            params.put("activityStreamId","1401");
            return params;

        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers=new HashMap<String,String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
            headers.put("cache-control","no-cache");
            headers.put("token",token);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    singletonclasshttp.getInstance(getActivity()).addtorequestque(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: u didn't set headers in request

Comment: @HarKal how should i do that? can you please help me with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049473/how-to-set-custom-header-in-volley-request

Comment: @HarKal i had added that in the code but still error exists.

Comment: got answer from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399526/post-request-with-volley